# corb fail to pull any file names have special characters

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I used CORB to export over thousands of records out of MarkLogic until it failed to get any file name with unique characters (-,/?!>..).  What can I do to resolve this?  I really appreciate any help you can provide.

The output directory is already existed with all permissions. But it fail to pull the file out of MarkLogic.

```
Caused by: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: SVC-FILOPN: xdmp:save("/output/XML/CB19A?M-N/A.xml", fn:doc("/documents/travelers/C19A?M-N/A.xml")) -- File open error: open /output/XML/C19A?M-N/A.xml': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters aren't allowed in file and directory names.

You will need to normalize the URI and translate into something that is a "safe" and valid file path.